# GDB+Python: Determining target type

Tags: python, gdb, coredump

Is there a way to determine whether the debugged target is a core dump or a 'live' process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no dedicated way to do it in Python, however, you can still use

- `gdb.execute("<command>", to_string=<boolean>)` to execute a "CLI" command in Python, where `to_string` being `True` will tell GDB to collect the output and return it as a string (cf. [doc](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html#Basic-Python))
- [`maint print target-stack`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Maintenance-Commands.html) which will print the layers used internally to access the inferior. You should see "`core (Local core dump file)`" if the core-debugging layer is active.

So all-in-all, a bit of code like

```
out = gdb.execute("maint print target-stack", to_string=True)
print "Local core dump file" in out
```

should do the trick.

Comment: @orgads don't forget to accept the answer if it solves the question, and up-vote it, if revelant ;)

Comment: oh, indeed, I didn't know that!